# How do I pass variables defined from argparse in config as a module to other scripts?

Tags: python, module, global-variables, argparse

The main problem I have is accessing variables defined in a configuration file as a module in other scripts when those variables are defined by argparse inputs. If I encapsulate this code within a function, I will not have access to it in other scripts. Similarly, if I don't use a function, the configuration file will expect inputs whenever it is called as a module. I think global variables might be the answer, but I don't know how to set them up in this use case?

````
import shutil
import inspect
import configparser
import sys
import argparse

def cmd_inputs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-dir','--geofloodhomedir',help="File path to directory that will hold the cfg file \
            and the inputs and outputs folders. Default is the GeoNet3 directory.",
            type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-p','--project',
            help="Folder within GIS, Hydraulics, and NWM directories \
            of Inputs and Outputs. Default is 'my_project'.",
            type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-n','--DEM_name',
            help="Name of Input DEM (without extension) and the prefix used for all \
            project outputs. Default is 'dem'",
            type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--no_chunk',help="Dont batch process DEM's > 1.5 GB for Network Extraction. Default is to chunk DEMs larger than 1.5 GB.",
            action='store_true')
    global home_dir
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.geofloodhomedir:
        home_dir = args.geofloodhomedir
        if os.path.abspath(home_dir) == os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)):
            home_dir = os.getcwd()
            print("hello")
        print('GeoNet and GeoFlood Home Directory: ')
        print(home_dir)
    else:
        ab_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
        home_dir = os.path.dirname(ab_path)
        print('Using default GeoNet and GeoFlood home directory:')
        print(home_dir)

    if args.project:
        project_name=args.project
        print(f"Project Name: {project_name}")
    else:
        project_name='my_project'
        print(f"Default Project Name: {project_name}")

    if args.DEM_name:
        dem_name = args.DEM_name
        print(f'DEM Name: {dem_name}')
    else:
        dem_name='dem'
        print(f'Default DEM: {dem_name}')
    if not args.no_chunk:
        print("Chunking DEMs > 1.5 GBs in Network Extraction script")
        chunk = 1
    else:
        print("Not chunking input DEM or its products in Network Extraction script")
        chunk = 0       


    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config['Section']={'geofloodhomedir':home_dir,
            'projectname':project_name,
            'dem_name':dem_name,
            'Chunk_DEM':chunk}
    with open(os.path.join(home_dir,'GeoFlood.cfg'),'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

if __name__=='__main__':
    cmd_inputs()
    print ("Configuration Complete")```
````

Comment: Often the code that defines the `parser` and calls `parse_args` is put in one function, which returns the `args` object.  That can be called in the `if __name__` block, defining `args` globally.  Other functions than get the whole `args`, or specific attributes.

Comment: But doesn't anything defined within main only get called when I run this script? How could I set this up such that when I import this script as a module, args is passed to the new script?

Comment: Generally you only want the command line parser to run when called as a script, and not when imported.  The arg or attributes are passes to functions as arguments.

Comment: I understand that. If I run the script directly, I parse the inputs and create a cfg file. I then want to be able to find the cfg file in other scripts when I import this script. The problem is that if I create a function outside of main to accept “args” as input, it will error when imported because the main script has not been run. Looking for an args that does not exist within that scope. How do I basically store the args created in main, such that when imported to a different script, I can access them?